# Oracle SQL to delete the records except last 7 days/1 week

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL DB for ERP JD Edwards.
Dates are stored in Julian Format for this ERP.

We usually use this code to convert date from Julian to normal format.
decode(szupmj,0,'  ',to_char(to_date(1900000 + olupmj,'YYYYDDD'),'MM/DD/YYYY'))

However we have a requirement where in, all data needs to be deleted except last 7 days.
Date column - 7

Please can someone help ?

| SZEDUS | SZEDBT | SZUPMJ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ILPPO | 74442 | 106108 |
| ILPPO | 74442 | 106108 |
| ILPPO | 77292 | 106109 |

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure, I have added to the original post.

Comment: we want data as text not images see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried to add the data as text but its getting messed up. Added in original post.

Comment: Ok, now the data is added in form of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your juliandate to a regular date and compare it to sysdate

Please test this first on a test database or use the dbfiddole to add rows with dates that are only a few days old

> ```
> CREATE TABLE dates (
>   "SZEDUS" VARCHAR(5),
>   "SZEDBT" INTEGER,
>   "SZUPMJ" INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dates
>   ("SZEDUS", "SZEDBT", "SZUPMJ")
> VALUES
>   ('ILPPO', '74442', '106108');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dates
>   ("SZEDUS", "SZEDBT", "SZUPMJ")
> VALUES
>
>   ('ILPPO', '74442', '106108');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dates
>   ("SZEDUS", "SZEDBT", "SZUPMJ")
> VALUES
>   ('ILPPO', '77292', '106109');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dates
> ```
>
> ```
> SZEDUS | SZEDBT | SZUPMJ
> :----- | -----: | -----:
> ILPPO  |  74442 | 106108
> ILPPO  |  74442 | 106108
> ILPPO  |  77292 | 106109
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM dates WHERE to_date(1900000 + SZUPMJ,'YYYYDDD') < trunc(sysdate) - 7
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dates
> ```
>
> ```
> SZEDUS | SZEDBT | SZUPMJ
> :----- | -----: | -----:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=892c9ff245b554def061e2a531da314d)*

Answer (score 0):

Do this in a PL/SQL block where you can compute the date you want and compare withthat. It's much more efficient than applying a function to transform the Julian-formatted dates to Gregorian dates:

```
DECLARE
  nCurr_date_minus_seven  NUMBER := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 7, 'YYYYDDD')) - 1900000;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM dates
    WHERE SZUPMJ < nCurr_date_minus_seven;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE  szupmj < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' DAY, 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000;
```

*(Which would be able to use an index on the `szupmj` column.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90e56bf4741f0d28cdb73e45f029c53e)*